# Why does using using the emoji's like  in chrome url caused the url to point to a random looking string?

Tags: google-chrome

I was basically trying to navigate to ".com" and found chrome to redirect to "http://xn--i28h.com/"

If you append anything before that string lets say "123.com" it points to  http://xn--123-9h33b.com/  ie the last characters got changed!

Tried to verify this behaviour on safari and it does not changes the URL.

Can anyone help me understand what those last digits after -- could represent ?

[image]

Comment: https://www.w3.org/International/articles/idn-and-iri/

Comment: why the reverse-engineering tag?

Comment: Or chrome, for that matter?

Comment: The behaviour is very specific to chrome.

Comment: Is it? Are you sure?

Comment: Only verified this on safari and the behaviour is different.

Comment: Hmm, for my (older version) browser it only shows "Safari can't find the server" maybe at the backend it has resolved the non-ascii characters but it does not reflects that in the URL like chrome does.

Comment: Did you have a chance to catch [my screenshot](https://monosnap.com/file/tHqtCCJBcvxkoY5IsPByDFWCXl5gD0.png)? It does resolve, but leaves the search bar untouched (usability reasons, maybe?)

Comment: Yup saw that, my version does not prints the "Safari can't open page ...." line

Comment: Ah. Understand the confusion then. Well, time to update the thing then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called [Punycode](https://www.punycoder.com/). This is how non-ascii characters in domain names are represented using ascii range.

More info: https://www.w3.org/International/articles/idn-and-iri/